# Loaded website with Selenium chromedriver successfully but can't interact with it after

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to interact with the Lowes website (https://www.lowes.com/) with Selenium and ChromeDriver. After I load the home page, I want to change the location, but I can't interact with the website. Clicking on the changing location button, both manually and through Selenium results in the page loading forever and eventually a TimeOutException thrown. Any ideas on why this might be the case and what could be done to resolve the problem?

I've loaded the website and interacted with it fine when I load it up manually with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer, so I don't think it's an issue with the website alone.

I've also used Selenium and ChromeDriver to load and interact with over 40 other websites with no issues at all, so I don't believe it is an issue with Selenium/ChromeDriver/Chrome and any version incompatibility issues. My Chrome is version 71.0.3578.98 and my driver version is 71.0.3578.137. I'm running my script (shown below) on Windows NT 6.1.761 SP1 x86_64 with Spyder on Python 3.6.

The code I'm running is as below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def click_button(x_path)
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x_path)))
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    pass

#the issue persists with and without the commented lines
url = 'https://www.lowes.com/'
try:
    #options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    #options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C://Temp//chromedriver.exe') #,options=options)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

#The following code hasn't worked, nor has manually interacting with the website at this point

sign_up_save_close = '//*[@id="emailSignUpDialog"]/div[2]/div/div/div/button
button_click(sign_up_save_close)

find_store_x_path = '//*[@id="currentStoreWrapper"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a'
button_click(find_store_x_path)
```

I suspect it might be an issue with how the website uniquely interacts with ChromeDriver.

I looked into whether the website knew that it was being interacted with by ChromeDriver, but there were no signs of the website actually detecting ChromeDriver and even with the customised option as shown above, the same issue persisted.

I've tried running it in Firefox with geockdriver, but I haven't been able to get my geckodriver to work. However, I want to keep this question about Chrome.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'll add in code to handle the Sign Up and Save, but the pop up is not the issue. Like I said, I've tried interacting with the website both manually and with code. Clicking on Find a Store ends up with the website loading forever. I'm also open to other solutions of accessing product pages on this website at certain locatons.

Comment: Did you handle the popup **SIGN UP & SAVE** through Selenium?

Comment: First you need to close popup..

Comment: @DebanjanB The issue is not with the popup. I've edited my post with code to close the popup but the site still loads forever upon trying to click 'Find a Store'.

Answer (score 0):

- You have defined the click function as `click_button()` but you are
  calling it as `button_click()`.
- You should always use an explicit wait instead of sleep.
- You have to wait for the close button to be clickable and after you click on the close button you have to wait for the modal to hide and the main page to be clickable.
- I've checked it with java. Click on the page works. But clicking on the `Find a store` button using chromedriver shows `Access Denied`. So apparently this site has selenium detection and blocking.